# R: how to make a column in a dataframe not recognized as a variable

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R with 5 columns. The first column contains the row names, but R is recognizing this as a variable so this is throwing errors for me in subsequent steps. Any ideas on how to make R recognize that these are rownames and not a variable? Many thanks for all the help!

**I am doing some gene sequencing analysis, and the dataframe contains the clinical information. As such, I would prefer to keep the dataframe intact since the rownames contain the identifiers to track individual samples.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the data.frame coming from? Are you reading it from a flat file (csv, tsv, etc) from disk? If you are using read.csv() function, it has the row.names argument, which can be set to 1 if your first column has row names.

```
data <- read.csv("/path/to/file.csv", row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never told us what you are doing with this dataframe, but one quick solution would be to just subset off the first row and then use that result in your calculations, i.e. use

```
df[2:nrow(df), ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am doing some gene sequencing analysis, and the dataframe contains the clinical information. As such, I would prefer to keep the dataframe intact since the rownames contain the identifiers to track individual samples. But many thanks for your help!

Comment: If the functions you are using do not permit a header row, you will have to get rid of it.